# Micronaut multiple instances of the same controller under different urls

Tags: micronaut

How can I instanciate multiple instances of the same controller class but expose it  under different url endpoints.

I need to be able to create multiple instances of the same controller class but each time under a different configurable sub url.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I instanciate multiple instances of the same controller class
>   but expose it under different url endpoints

You can't have multiple instances of the same controller each responding to a different configurable URL.  However, there is no good reason to do that.  There are a number of ways to have multiple different urls share code and the particulars of how to do that depend on what it is you are really trying to accomplish.

The answer to the question as asked is that you can't.

Comment: I am trying to do kind of proxy to an external system and depending on the url I would like to call different external system endpoints with small variations on the parameters to pass depending on the sub url that I received. I am guessing now that I need to use a URI template matching pattern. Thank you.

Comment: There isn't enough info in your comment to know for sure but one thing to consider is use a single instance of a single controller class and map to a URI like `@Get("/something/{var1}/{var2}/etc")`.

Comment: "I need to be able to create multiple instances of the same controller class but each time under a different configurable sub url." - Micronaut doesn't support that and that wouldn't be the right solution to your situation even if it did.